# How to use tf.FixedLenFeature with tf.string with parse_example and input_from_feature_columns?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some data stored in TFRecords, with some categorical data stored in byteslist. I am able to examine the data by hand and verify that the data are there. One Example record looks like:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "label"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: 1
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "col1"
    value {
      float_list {
        value: -1.15293061733
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "col2"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "vPlNwEdfGNA8"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I try to convert the columns to tensors using `tf.contrib.layers.input_from_feature_columns` as shown below, I get an error.

```
features_batch = tf.parse_example(
    serialized_batch,
    features={
        'col1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
        # 'col2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value=''), # This does not work
        'col2': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string), # This works
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    })

# Convert columns to Tensor
col2_hash = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket('col2', hash_bucket_size=1e6)

deep_cols = [
    tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('col1'),
    tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(col2_hash, dimension=8)
]

deep_batch = tf.contrib.layers.input_from_feature_columns(features_batch, deep_cols)
```

The error is:

```
    deep_batch = tf.contrib.layers.input_from_feature_columns(features_batch, deep_cols)
  File "/.virtualenvs/analytics-models/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 109, in input_from_feature_columns
    transformed_tensor = transformer.transform(column)
  File "/.virtualenvs/analytics-models/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py", line 583, in transform
    feature_column.insert_transformed_feature(self._columns_to_tensors)
  File "/.virtualenvs/analytics-models/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 868, in insert_transformed_feature
    self.sparse_id_column.insert_transformed_feature(columns_to_tensors)
  File "/.virtualenvs/analytics-models/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py", line 473, in insert_transformed_feature
    sparse_values = sparse_tensor.values
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'values'
```

This works if I parse it as a `tf.VarLenFeature`, but it is not sparse so it seems weird to treat it that way.

Any ideas why I cannot import the string values into a `tf.FixedLenFeature` and then crease a `sparse_column_with_hash_bucket` with it?

Comment: It's not supported; FixedLenFeature doesn't produce a SpasrseTensor so the sparse column doesn't work with it.